# How do I beat the Stone Spirit in the Deep Roads in Dragon Age 2?

Tags: dragon-age-2

Does the Stone Spirit have any vulnerabilities? I have both Hawkes, Isabela and Varric in my party. I don't have any tanks with me. Does the Stone Spirit have any weaknesses (ice, fire, etc.)?

Comment: Refresh my memory, is this the giant spider like thing that you fight where there are 4 pillars in the room?

Comment: No this is Stone Ghost which you have to kill to get a key from the door to escape from trap in the Deep Roads.

Comment: Do you have the name of the monster specifically? It's been too long since I've played the game and my searches on the Dragon Age Wiki is coming up empty. You may be able to find your answer here: http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Age_Wiki

Comment: Yes I think that Stone Ghost is the name of the monster: http://tinyurl.com/6e2zthh. I've tried to kill him for one week on the medium level and as I see I can't make this without the tank if I will not find any weaknesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be the "Ancient Rock Wraith" you are fighting?

I only bothered playing through on Casual so I just beat him to death with relative ease, but if you search for "Ancient Rock Wraith" in the following guide it shows weaknesses and some tips...

http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/988967-dragon-age-ii/faqs/61965